# computing Newton-Cotes weights

Tags: quadrature

For the [closed Newton-Cotes quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cotes_formulas#Closed_Newton.E2.80.93Cotes_formulae) over $[x_1, x_n]$, the coefficients $H_{n,i}$ for
$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_n} f(x)\:\text{d}x = h \sum_{i=1}^n H_{n,i} \; f(x_i)
$$
are given explicitly by
$$
H_{n,r+1} =\frac{(-1)^{n-r}}{r!(n-r)!}\int_0^n \frac{\prod_{k=0}^n (t-k)}{t-r}\:\text{d}t;
$$
see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-CotesFormulas.html.

To compute those values numerically, one could go ahead and evaluate the integral, but perhaps that's not the most efficient thing to do. [SciPy does something else](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.0/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py#L774-L855), but I don't quite get it.

Any hints?

Comment: Is your question *why* SciPy does something different? Are they just using a different equation that, however, evaluates to the same number?

Comment: They are the same numbers, but I don't understand what they are doing (any why). No reference given in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can explain what the scipy code is doing (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.0/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py#L833-L842). I haven't checked this directly, but this should be correct in principle.

The line `ti = 2 * yi - 1` remaps the interval $(0,1)$ to $(-1,1)$, so now the weights will be the integrals of Lagrange elementary interpolants over $(-1,1)$ with nodes $(-1:2/N:1)$.

The line `C = ti ** nvec[:, np.newaxis]` constructs the (transpose of) the Vandermonde matrix, with entries $C_{ij} = t_i ^ j$. This matrix has the property that when multiplied on the left by a vector $\alpha$, it produces
$$\alpha^\top C = (p_\alpha(t_0), \ldots, p_\alpha(t_N))$$
which is the vector of $p_\alpha$ (polynomial with coefficients being the entries of $\alpha$) evaluated at each $t_0,\ldots,t_N$.

The inverse of this, $C^{-1}$, will then consist of vectors $\alpha_k$ that give the coefficients of Lagrange interpolants, because $\alpha_k^\top C = e_k$, and having $p_{\alpha_k}(t_l) = \delta_{kl}$ is the definition of Lagrange interpolants.

The Vandermonde matrix is very ill-conditioned, so scipy applies twice the Newton-Raphson iteration for the (matrix) reciprocal: `Cinv = 2*Cinv - Cinv.dot(C).dot(Cinv)`.

Once the coefficients of Lagrange interpolants, $C^{-1}$, are known, it is straightforward to integrate them, by multiplying $C^{-1}$ on the right with $(2/1, 0, 2/3, 0, 2/5, \ldots)^\top$ (the integrals of $x^m$ for odd $m$ are zero—the integral is over $(-1,1)$ because of `ti` above), which gives the Newton-Cotes weights: `ai = Cinv[:, ::2].dot(vec) * (N / 2.)`

Comment: You should propose a pull request that adds your explanation to the documentation of that function.

Answer (score 0):

In the pass I did something similarly. At the time I applied Gauss-Legendre quadrature to evaluate $H_{n,r+1}$ intergals; this calculation adopted (1) Gauss-Legendre weight and points calculated in advance (then, change the variable $t$ in the integrand to $\xi \in [-1,1]$), and (2) multi-precision floating point library [fmlib](http://myweb.lmu.edu/dmsmith/fmlib.html).

I guess that you obtain $H_{n,i} $ from Lagrange Interpolation Formulae. Let me review some basic thing so that you may recognize the same derivation. From the Lagrange Interpolation, we have 
\begin{align}
 f(x)
=
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}
 l_i (x) 
 f_i
+
 R_n (x)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
 l_i (x) 
&=
 \frac{
  \Pi_n( x) 
 }{
  (x-x_i)
 } 
 .
 \frac{
  1
 }{
  \Pi _n ' (x_i) 
 } 
=
 \frac{
  ( x - x_1 ) 
  \ldots 
  ( x - x_{i-1} )
  ( x - x_{i+1} )
  \ldots 
  ( x - x_{n} )
 }{
  ( x_i - x_1 ) 
  \ldots 
  ( x_i - x_{i-1} )
  ( x_i - x_{i+1} )
  \ldots 
  ( x_i - x_{n} )
 } ,
\\
 R_n (x) 
&=
 \frac{ f^{(n)} (\xi) }{ n! } \cdot 
 \Pi _n (x)  
   ,
\end{align}
for some $\xi = \xi(x) \in (x_1, x_n )$. 
Note that 
we defined
$ 
 \Pi_n (x)
=
 \prod_{i=1}^{n}
 (x-x_i)
$, 
and we also have 
\begin{align}
 \left| R_n (x) \right| 
&\le 
 \frac{ ( x_n - x_1 )^{n} }{ n! }
 \max_{ x_1 \le x \le x_n } \left| f^{(n)} (x) \right|
\end{align}
which can be proved using the Role’s theorem.

Now we take 
\begin{align}
 \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
 f(x) 
 d x 
&=
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}
   \underbrace{
 \left( 
  \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
   l_i (x) 
  d x 
 \right) 
   }_{ A_ i }
 f_i
+
   \underbrace{
 \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
  R_n (x)
 d x 
   }_{ B }
\end{align}
Define 
\begin{align}
   A_ i 
&=   
   \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
    l_i (x) 
   d x ~~~(\equiv H_{n,i} ? )
\\
   B
&=
 \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
  R_n (x)
 d x 
\end{align}
We are going to estimate those integrals. Change variable,
\begin{align}
   h 
&=
   \frac{ x_n  - x_1 }{ n - 1 }
,~~~~~
   x = x_1 + (t-1) h
,~~
   \forall t \in [1,n]
\end{align}
Using the latter one, $x - x_j = x_1 + (t-1)h - x_j $ and 
$ x_j = x_1 + (j-1) h $, 
we have 
$$
   x - x_j 
   = 
   x_1 + (t-1)h - 
   \left[ x_1 + (j-1)h \right] 
   =
   (t-j)h 
$$
Thus 
\begin{align}
   A_ i
&=   
   \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
    l_i (x) 
   d x 
=
 \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
 \frac{
  ( x - x_1 ) 
  \ldots 
  ( x - x_{i-1} )
  ( x - x_{i+1} )
  \ldots 
  ( x - x_{n} )
 }{
  ( x_i - x_1 ) 
  \ldots 
  ( x_i - x_{i-1} )
  ( x_i - x_{i+1} )
  \ldots 
  ( x_i - x_{n} )
 } 
 d x 
\\
&=
 \int_{1}^{n}
   \frac{
   h ( t - 1 ) 
   \cdot  
   h ( t - 2 )
   \cdots
   h ( t-i+1 )
   \cdot 
   h (t-i-1)
   \cdots
   h(t-n)
   }{ 
    h ( i - 1 ) 
   \cdot  
   h ( i - 2 )
   \cdots
   h ( i-i+1 )
   \cdot 
   h (i-i-1)
   \cdots
   h(i-n)
   }
   \cdot 
   h d t 
\end{align}
Or
\begin{align}
   A_ i
&=
   h 
 \int_{1}^{n}
   \frac{
   ( t - 1 ) 
   \cdot  
   ( t - 2 )
   \cdots
   ( t-i+1 )
   \cdot 
   (t-i-1)
   \cdots
   (t-n)
   }{ 
   ( i - 1 ) 
   \cdot  
   ( i - 2 )
   \cdots
   ( i-i+1 )
   \cdot 
   (i-i-1)
   \cdots
   (i-n)
   }
   d t 
\end{align}
And 
\begin{align}
   B
&=   
   \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
    R_n (x) 
   d x 
=
 \int_{x_1}^{x_n}
  ( x - x_1 ) 
  \ldots 
      ( x - x_{i} )
  \ldots 
  ( x - x_{n} )
      \cdot 
      \frac{ f^{(n)} (\xi (x) ) }{ n! }  
 d x 
\\
&=
 \int_{1}^{n}
   h ( t - 1 ) 
   \cdot  
   h ( t - 2 )
   \cdots
   h ( t - i)
   \cdots
   h(t-n)
   \cdot 
   \frac{ f^{(n)} (\xi (x(t)) ) }{ n! }  
   \cdot 
   h d t 
\end{align}
We estimate
\begin{align}
   | B | 
&\le
   M 
   h^{n+1}
\end{align}
where $M = |C_n | \sup_{ \xi \in [x_1,x_n]  } \left| f^{(n)} (\xi) \right| $
and 
\begin{align}
   C_n
&=
   \frac{1}{ n! }
 \int_{1}^{n}
   ( t - 1 ) 
   \cdots
   ( t - i)
   \cdots
   ( t - n )
   d t 
\label{c}
\end{align}
Here integrals $A_i$ and $C_n$ can be estimated EXACTLY using
Gauss-Legendre formulas with $n/2$ points.

As I could see in numerical result at the time, we have (a) $A_i $ are increased to very large values as $n$ increasing, for example $\max A_i \sim 10^{0}, 10^{2}, 10^{4}, 10^{7}, 10^{10}$ and $10^{24}$ when $n=10,20,30,40,50$, and $100$, respectively; (b) $A_i$ is symmetry with repect to $i$, i.e. $A_{i} = A_{n-i+1}$; (c) $\sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{i} = n-1$; and (c) $C_n = 0$ for $n$ odd, and $C_n$ is bounded by a small value when $n$ even.